# Push Notification Action Categories are not working in killed state iOS

Tags: push-notification

My Push notifications action categories are not working, while the app is in suspended(killed) state, in Background & foreground everything is working fine & also I'm receiving notifications in all the states.

Actually, I want to store some data in firebase, on click of 'Accept' & 'Reject' buttons which is the action categories of Push Notification.

Please help me, I'm stuck in this place

Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: I'm having same issue. Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Same here, some news ? please ? Everything works good when foreground or background.

Comment: I research a lot and I found that Push Notification Action Categories will not work in the terminated state of an application. (It will only work in foreground and background mode)

Answer (score 0):

Have to add these methods in AppDelegate. It should work.

1. `application(_:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:)`
2. `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`.

Comment: I research a lot and I found that Push Notification Action Categories is not work in the terminated state of an application. (It will only work in foreground and background mode)